# php: Does memory_limit setting influence running time / speed?

Tags: php, memory, performance

If I increase php memory_limit could that increase the speed of a process?

Or if there is more memory allowed than needed the extra resource will not be used by the system to increase speed of the current process?

Comment: Dude, whoever downvoted it explain why. Lame troll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it will not improve the performance. This is just a limit on the maximum allowed memory consumption of a php script. If your script tries to exceed this limit, you will get an error.